# In search of formatting of Screen tip

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, popups

Is there any way where I can increase the font size of screen tip. In the slide show... it is so small and not so visible for a huge audience presentation.

Comment: What screen tips are you referring to? Perhaps a screenshot of one, by way of example, would help you get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

PPT picks up its screen tip/tooltips size from the Windows settings.  You need to change your display settings in Windows to increase the size in PPT.  How you do it depends on the version of Windows you have.